# Finding ranges of a parameter for which a function is always positive

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I have a complex function of a single variable expressed in analytical form, which also depends on a parameter. I would like to have Mathematica show me for which values of the parameter the real part of the second derivative of the function is always positive.

Strictly speaking, maybe I have given too much detail here, the real part/derivative stuff is ultimately inessential, what I want Mathematica to do is to tell me for what choices of a parameter a real function is positive everywhere. I hope the question is clear, though.

Comment: If you need a numerical approximation for a function that can't be treated analytically, you can use `RegionPlot`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For example, [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html):

```
Reduce[
 ForAll[x, α*x^2 + β*x + γ > 0],
 {α, β, γ},
 Reals
]
```

which looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

tells us that $\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma>0$ for all $x$ if these conditions hold:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or [`Resolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Resolve.html):

```
Resolve[
 ForAll[x, α*x^2 + β*x + γ > 0] && x ∈ Reals,
 Reals
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!